# Jquery-ajax doesn't succeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am quite new to to ajax, just learning it, and made a simple page on localhost to test gets and posts from/to json file in the same folder.

While GET is working smoothly, I cannot figure out, why post doesn't happen if I click the button I assigned this function to.
Pls take a look into my code and help.

```
element = $("#mylist");
var item2 = $("#mytable");

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "data.json",
  success: function(response) {
    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
      element.append("<li>" + item.fname + " " + item.lname + "</li>");
      item2.append("<tr><td>" + item.lname + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.fname + "</td></tr>");
    });
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("error");
  }
});

$("#additem").on('click', function() {
  var $fname = $("#fname");
  var $lname = $("#lname");
  var $city = $("#city");
  var order = {
    fname: $fname.val(),
    lname: $lname.val(),
    city: $city.val()
  };
  console.log(order);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "data.json",
    data: order,
    succes: function() {
      console.log("succes");
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("no success");
    }
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u1qsjhm/)

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Is your server configured to return data to a POST request as it is for a GET? Also, please put all relevant code in the question. The restriction warning which you've worked around is there for a reason.

Comment: You can't POST to a `.json` file, it is not a server side script that gets executed like php

Comment: I agree with @PatrickEvans and you are missing an "s" in "success"

Comment: This is probably due to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: Use: `error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }` to see what the actual errors - could be ".json file is read-only" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to post to a .json file, like Patrick Evans says in the comments. You need to do the post to a script, in PHP you could do something like this:

```
$order = $_POST['order'];
// Do something with order...
echo $order; // or echo success message
```

Of course for this to work you will need PHP to be running on your server (localhost).